# How to overwrite the attachment for List Item CSOM C#?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, attachments

I am using following code to attach the image file to the list item using C# CSOM.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
    ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
    var attachment = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
    attachment.FileName = "fileName.jpg";
    attachment.ContentStream = fs; // My file stream
    Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachment);
    clientContext.Load(att);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

It work fine, but when I try to attach the file with the same name then it throw an error:

> The specified name is already in use.The document or folder name was
>   not changed.  To change the name to a different value, close this
>   dialog and edit the properties of the document or folder

I want that previous file should be overwrite with new file. I am unable to find any properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no overwrite feature for attachments. Best alternative is to check if similar file exists then delete and upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work with `item.AttachmentFiles.Add` method. But you can use `SaveBinaryDirect` method to overwrite the attachment.

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");                
var attachFilePath = @"C:\abcd.jpg";
var listItem = list.GetItemById(4);
context.Load(listItem);
context.ExecuteQuery();
using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileInfo(attachFilePath).Open(System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, "/sites/GautamTestSite/Lists/CustomList/Attachments/" + listItem.Id + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(attachFilePath), fileStream, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll revert back once I am done with implementing this code.

Comment: hey @TrimantraSoftwareSolution, any luck here ? I tried the code and its working for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to add an item or update it if its already exists.

```
void AddOrUpdateListItemAttachment(ClientContext ctx, ListItem item, string fileName, Stream fileContent)
        {
            var file = item.AttachmentFiles.Where(a => a.FileName.Equals(fileName)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (file != null)
            {
                file.DeleteObject();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            AttachmentCreationInformation attach = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
            attach.FileName = fileName;
            attach.ContentStream = fileContent;
            item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attach);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Make sure when you pass `ListItem` object to this function it must be loaded along with its property `"AttachmentFiles"`. You can use following code to load item.

`ctx.Load(listItem, i => i.AttachmentFiles);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of [@Amal Hashim](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34350/amal-hashim) and with reference to following:

- [AttachmentCreationInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachmentcreationinformation_properties.aspx) properties
- [AttachmentCreationInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachmentcreationinformation_members.aspx) members

Available members are:

[image]

We can say that there are no ways to overwrite the attachment using `AttachmentCreationInformation`.

If anyone has some more reference then are welcomed to provide here.